# To remove whitespace or newline for the string value fetched from the text file

Tags: linux

**sample.txt** file contains below values

```
1111
2222
3333
```

With above values will be frames to access the folder with names `1111`, `2222`, `3333`
I'm referring these values using below code

```
for i in $(cat sample.txt); do cd folder1/$i; done
```

it gives error as `can't cd : folder1/1111`

Reason because each string values referred from the file has some suffice whitespace or new line character ..not sure exactly

I tried below commands with no success

```
for i in $(cat sample.txt); do i = $(echo ${i::-1 }); cd folder1/$i; done
for i in $(cat sample.txt); do i = $(echo $i | tr -d "[:space:]"); cd folder1/$i; done
for i in $(cat sample.txt); do cd folder1/$i; done
```

Comment: I test your first code and it is executed correctly. It seems that you are doing something wrong, and you have not mentioned it here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't get the error for the first line, but starting from the second line only.

If you have successfully done

```
cd folder1/1111
```

the command

```
cd folder1/2222
```

will fail because you already are in `folder1/1111`.

You should `cd` back to the original directory or do the `cd` and whatever else you want to do in a subshell.

BTW: You should not read the lines with `for`, because this will fail if you have a line that contains a space.
See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor
and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

This should work

```
while read -r dir
do
    ( cd "folder1/$dir" ) # ( ... ) to use a subshell
    # after leaving the subshell, here we are back in the original directory
done < sample.txt
```

Comment: What I observed here is each word fetched from the sample.txt file has some space added to it hence it fails to access the directory. Where as the last word doesn’t cause this issue. So if I could remove the space at the end of the each word, should resolve the issue. To remove that space I tried the above mentioned command but it didn’t resolve

Comment: @Umesh Do you see the space in the file `sample.txt`? If yes, then add a piece of your real input to your question that allows us to test a proposed script. In any case you should copy & paste the exact error message. In your question you cite an error message: `can't cd : folder1/1111`. Where is the space that is supposed to lead to the problem?